# Searching from File title as well as file content in media library

Tags: kentico

I managed to Search the contents of text files using custom search as described in the link below: https://docs.kentico.com/k8/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/smart-search-api/creating-custom-smart-search-indexes

But it is not able to search in the filename. For example, if my search text is "Roman", the file "RomanRaj.txt" should show up in the results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file name to your search index by index content customization. See the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k81/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/smart-search-api-and-customization/customizing-the-content-of-search-indexes) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest NOT creating a custom smart search index but [look at using attachments](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/searching-attachment-files) and searching those.  Out of the box, Kentico will allow you to search attachments and their contents without writing any code.